# Textarea with autocomplete and some validation control in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typeahead

I am using angular 4 in my application. As part of some search functionality, I want build component similar to advanced search in JIRA. It should have icon which will show search criteria is valid or not. Autocomplete functionality which provides list of suggestive text. If there is existing angular component which supports such functionality will definitely be helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this component https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-text-input-autocomplete whose demo you can try here https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-text-input-autocomplete/

It seems to fit your needs, but you may need to customize it to fit your use case.